# Turn off Intellij auto adding to VCS/Git

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

I've accidentally turned on automatic addition of new files into Git and clicked 'Remember my decision, don't ask again' (or whatever the option actually is) and now I'm unable to change the selection in Preferences |> Version Control |> Confirmation, those options are greyed out. Is there a way to disable this again?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 - Go to:

File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation -> When Files are created

Here you can configure how IDEA behaves for when a file is added or deleted (and other scenarios), options: 
- silently adds file to Git or display popup with options or if it should do nothing

select option: "Do Not Add"

Comment: To turn it back on, check "add silently" and "including external files".

Comment: Is it possible to set it for all projects instead of the current project?

Comment: You can also set this setting for all new projects using `File -> New Project Settings -> Settings for New Projects...`

Comment: In IntelliJ 2021.2.1, it's now called `File -> New Projects Setup -> ...`

Answer (score 6):

Preferences |> Version Control |> Confirmation is the only place to configure this behavior.

This is a common functionality, not only for git. I have never seen it disabled. Does it happen for all controls in the Confirmation node? What about other options under Version control? Doesn't IDE restart help?